# ST_DWithin use_spheroid argument for data projected in Web Mercator

Tags: postgis

When calling `ST_DWithin` in order to fetch data to overlay an area selected on a Web Mercator map, should `false` be passed to the `use_spheroid` argument of the call to [`ST_DWithin`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), since Web Mercator assumes a perfectly spherical earth? While not geodesically precise, I presume reducing accuracy by using the simplified formulae would actually increase the accuracy of matching the data to the area selected on the map?

Comment: The choice of `use_spheroid` parameter doesn't really depend on the type of projection. However, it requires the `geography` type of lng/lat data, so it won't work with Web Mercator without transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Most coordinate reference systems embed the definition of a rotational ellipsoid (spheroid), which expresses a better approximation of the earth (or rather the geoid). Performing computations on a reference ellipsoid require more computational power than calculations performed on the sphere (simple spherical trigonometry).

Web Mercator is based on a sphere, even though WGS84 coordinates are being used. Thus, it does not matter in your case. Therefore I would take "false" as input.